# How to check offline mode using MobileFirst Platform?

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using the below code in app\common\js\main.js

1. On clicking a button we are setting heatbeat to 5 seconds so that every 5 seconds MobileFirst Server will trigger one of the two events: "WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED" or "WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED".
2. I have added event listeners for these two events and in their callback handlers I have logged some info into console.

Result: when I click on the button, then the console is updated every 5 seconds (some console.trace from worklight.js), but, the info which I logged using console.log is visible only for the first time. It is not visible on subsequent event triggers.

Can you suggest what's going wrong?

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    document.addEventListener(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED, connectDetected, false); 
    document.addEventListener(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED, disconnectDetected , false);
}

function disconnectDetected(){
    var output = new Date() + "<hr />disconnectDetected";
    console.log(output);
}

function connectDetected(){
    var output = new Date() + "<hr />connectDetected";  
    console.log(output);
}

function setHeartBeatInterval(interval){

    WL.Client.setHeartBeatInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: What is the Worklight version and its *build number*?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "when I click on the button, then the console is updated every 5 seconds (some console.trace from worklight.js), but, the info which I logged using console.log is visible only for the first time."? Unless the server state changes, that event will be fired only once. You're connected - the event is fired. You're disconnected - the event is fired. And so on, only if the event is fired.

Comment: I am using platform version 6.3.0.00.20141127-1357

Comment: Ahh is it.. 
I thought that if we set heartbeat then one of the events is fired every specified seconds..

Comment: Just like you suggested, I tried changing server state. Event fires on server state change only.. Thanks Idan :)

Comment: and thanks for correcting me on use of MobileFirst instead of Worklight :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED` and `WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED` get fired only if the server state changes.

So if you're sending requests to the server and then for some reason it's unreachable, the _DISCONNCETED event will get fired. If you then send a request and the server is successfully pinged, the _CONNECTED event will get fired.

Comment: Yep... :)
I am learning MobileFirst by myself
Could you tell me what is the most used method to detect internet connection for mobile applications?

Comment: You can read about WL.Device.getNetworkInfo: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Device.html?cp=SSHS8R_6.3.0%2F9-1-0-1-0&lang=en

Comment: @IdanAdar so, throughout the application, if we wanted to handle events differently based on connection, would we check if WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED each time?